# can't set vim spellfile relative to HOME on mac

Tags: vim, spell-checking

I have installed vim on mac using homebrew and as I'm trying to configure spellchecking I'm facing an issue.
When I set try to set the `spellfile` (either within my vimrc or using vim `:set`  commands I get the error below:

```
invalid argument: spellfile=~/.vim/spell/mywordlist.utf-8.add
```

So basically in my vimrc if I have:

```
set spellfile=~/.vim/spell/alxgomz.utf-8.add
```

I get the error above. But If I use:

```
set spellfile=.vim/spell/alxgomz.utf-8.add
```

The error goes away but of course the spellfile is only found if pwd is home dir...

The config works ok on my linux box but not on my mac. I've also tried using $HOME instead of "~" but that doesn't help. Neither does quoting (single or double)...

Anyone faced that or know how to acheive specifying a spellfile remative to homedir on mac?

Edit:

```
VIM - Vi IMproved 8.2 (2019 Dec 12, compilé Mar 12 2022 12:21:28)
Version macOS - x86_64
Rustines incluses : 1-4550
Compilé par Homebrew
Énorme version sans interface graphique.
  Fonctionnalités incluses (+) ou non (-) :
+acl               +file_in_path      +mouse_urxvt       -tag_any_white
+arabic            +find_in_path      +mouse_xterm       -tcl
+autocmd           +float             +multi_byte        +termguicolors
+autochdir         +folding           +multi_lang        +terminal
-autoservername    -footer            -mzscheme          +terminfo
-balloon_eval      +fork()            +netbeans_intg     +termresponse
+balloon_eval_term +gettext           +num64             +textobjects
-browse            -hangul_input      +packages          +textprop
++builtin_terms    +iconv             +path_extra        +timers
+byte_offset       +insert_expand     +perl              +title
+channel           +ipv6              +persistent_undo   -toolbar
+cindent           +job               +popupwin          +user_commands
-clientserver      +jumplist          +postscript        +vartabs
+clipboard         +keymap            +printer           +vertsplit
+cmdline_compl     +lambda            +profile           +vim9script
+cmdline_hist      +langmap           -python            +viminfo
+cmdline_info      +libcall           +python3           +virtualedit
+comments          +linebreak         +quickfix          +visual
+conceal           +lispindent        +reltime           +visualextra
+cryptv            +listcmds          +rightleft         +vreplace
+cscope            +localmap          +ruby              +wildignore
+cursorbind        +lua               +scrollbind        +wildmenu
+cursorshape       +menu              +signs             +windows
+dialog_con        +mksession         +smartindent       +writebackup
+diff              +modify_fname      -sodium            -X11
+digraphs          +mouse             -sound             -xfontset
-dnd               -mouseshape        +spell             -xim
-ebcdic            +mouse_dec         +startuptime       -xpm
+emacs_tags        -mouse_gpm         +statusline        -xsmp
+eval              -mouse_jsbterm     -sun_workshop      -xterm_clipboard
+ex_extra          +mouse_netterm     +syntax            -xterm_save
+extra_search      +mouse_sgr         +tag_binary        
-farsi             -mouse_sysmouse    -tag_old_static    
         fichier vimrc système : "$VIM/vimrc"
     fichier vimrc utilisateur : "$HOME/.vimrc"
  2e fichier vimrc utilisateur : "~/.vim/vimrc"
      fichier exrc utilisateur : "$HOME/.exrc"
 fichier de valeurs par défaut : "$VIMRUNTIME/defaults.vim"
               $VIM par défaut : "/usr/local/share/vim"
Compilation : clang -c -I. -Iproto -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -DMACOS_X -DMACOS_X_DARWIN -g -O2 -D_REENTRANT -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=1 
Édition de liens : clang -L. -fstack-protector-strong -L/usr/local/lib -L/usr/local/opt/libyaml/lib -L/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/lib -L/usr/local/opt/readline/lib -L/usr/local/lib -o vim -lm -lncurses -liconv -lintl -framework AppKit -L/usr/local/opt/lua/lib -llua5.4 -mmacosx-version-min=12.0 -fstack-protector-strong -L/usr/local/lib -L/usr/local/Cellar/perl/5.34.0/lib/perl5/5.34.0/darwin-thread-multi-2level/CORE -lperl -L/usr/local/opt/python@3.10/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/config-3.10-darwin -lpython3.10 -framework CoreFoundation -lruby.3.1 -L/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/3.1.1/lib
```

As requested in comments

Comment: How exactly are you setting it? (This is probably also more on-topic for vim.stackexchange.com.)

Comment: Sorry that was a mistake in typing. I don't have any space in my vimrc and I do have an "=" sign.

Comment: `vim --version | grep spell` ?

Comment: `$ vim --version | grep spell` gives  `-dnd               -mouseshape        +spell             -xim`

Comment: `+spell` is ok.

Comment: Could you add the full output of `$ vim --version` to your question? Possibly related to https://github.com/vim/vim/issues/7230.

Comment: added to the main question. Thank you